# struts multi-dimensional map-backed action form

Tags: java, html, struts

I'm trying to use a 2-dimensional map in a struts 1 action form.  I have reviewed the struts documentation of map-backed action forms here http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/building_controller.html.  However this is for a 1-dimensional map.  I have gotten it to work but I don't like my solution.  Essentially, I have to pass in a combo key to my setter and getter and split the combo key into the correct keys.  Is there an alternate way to do this.

```
public FooForm extends ActionForm {

    private final Map<String, Map<String,String>> values = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();

    public void setValue(String key, Object value) {
        String[] keys = key.split("_");
        if (keys.length == 2) {
            Map<String, String> innerValues = costValues.get(keys[0]);
            if (innerValues == null) {
                innerValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
            }
            innerValues.put(keys[1], value);
            values.put(keys[0], innerValues);
        }
    }

    public String getValue(String key) {
        String[] keys = key.split("_");
        if (keys.length == 2) {
            Map<String, String> innerValues = values.get(keys[0]);
            if (innerValues != null) {
                return innerValues.get(keys[1]);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

<html:text property="value(foo_bar)"/>
```